# Request: User Unban, merge accounts

Tags: support, question-quality

Being a beginner w.r.t programming, I had many questions, which seemed rather offensive and silly to the Stack Overflow community.

My account got banned on Stack Overflow a few days ago after I requested for / deleted my own questions.

I also admit, I didn't realize what kind of questions should be asked on Stack Overflow. But the rules/faq weren't plain clear to me. And I thought every question I asked, had an answer.

I must also say that SO community is very strict when compared to other StackExchange sites.

Here's my request...

- unblock my account, and allow me to clear my doubts and become a good programmer
- merge my two accounts ([older one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844906/aahan), [new one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860672/aahan)) - - I am about to abandon my older email and hence had to create a new account which got banned
- some clear-cut guidelines as to what I `SHOULD NOT` ask at stackoverflow.com

**EDIT:** Thanks to someone (mod or supermod) who just unblocked my account. This community means a lot to me. Thanks for letting me in.

Comment: Moderators can't unblock your account. It's likely that someone upvoted one of your questions, moving you from just below the block threshold to just above.

Comment: The only way a mod could have helped would be if he undeleted a question, but that's about all we can do.

Comment: @Gilles, Won't : Well, what they did was merge my two accounts. One account had just enough reputation to get me out of the ban. Lucky me!

Comment: I want my account unblocked too :3

Answer (score 5):

The rules/faq are spelled out in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), which you are supposed to have read. I can't see your deleted questions, so I can't comment on them. Read the FAQ, especially [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). Browse the site a little to get a feeling for how things are done.

In my experience, Stack Overflow is not stricter or laxer than other Stack Exchange sites. On the other hand, Stack Overflow is less patient. If you post a bad question on some smaller Stack Exchange site, it's relatively common that someone will edit out the bad parts or give you custom guidance as to how to improve it. Stack Overflow is more of a “big city”: if you fall down, don't expect anyone to hold your hand.

If your account was automatically blocked for low quality (as opposed to, say, suspended by a moderator), you can lift the block by posting some answers that gather a few upvotes.

Comment: It's impossible for me to unblock/unban myself as I am a total noob at the moment, and can't answer any question posted on SO (especially because I haven't even started programming). I am learning, and Stack Exchange sites have been of great help so far. I tried, but every question is out of my knowledge. So, is there no way around? :(

Comment: @Aahan Are you sure your questions haven't already been asked and answered? Try browsing and searching [SO] as you learn. As you get more experience, you will start to be able to post answers as well.

Comment: @Anna Lear Why shouldn't some friendly moderator unblock me and give me a second chance? And of course, I always search (Google, here, everywhere) before posting a question.

Comment: @Aahan Moderators cannot revert an automatic question-asking ban.

Comment: @Anna Lear which means the only way is to answer some questions and get some up votes... (impossible for a beginner like me, I tried). Anyway, thanks Anna.