# Error message when trying to view a profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Browsing [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101800/152101), I notice that Gilles says he can't see deleted questions.  That gets me curious as to exactly what his rep is on SO so I click on his name and I get the error page.  I can't view my own profile either though random others seem to still work.

What did me and Gilles do that made MSO not like us anymore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing to see here, move along :)

Comment: Can I at least know why me and Gilles are so special?

Comment: Someone checked in some code that operated on the "About Me" string, but didn't do a null check.  OH, THOSE PESKY NULLS!

Comment: Wait, are you trying to make this my fault for not filling my "About me"?  :P

Comment: It was more Gilles' fault - come on, everyone should fill out their profile; you even get a [badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/9/autobiographer "Autobiographer") for it!

Answer (score 0):

I just got a message that we're in maintenance mode.